# Different performance between sendto and recvfrom

Tags: c, sockets, udp, sendto, elapsedtime

I have noticed that there is a difference of performance between sendto and recvfrom (UDP). I send about 100Kbytes from a server to a client, using WiFi (the estimated bandwidth is about 30Mb/s in both directions), and the sending time is about 4-5 ms (it depends, but this value is comparable to the ideal one, 3ms). On the client, the receiving time is ten-fifteen times higher, like 50-60ms. I'd like to have the two elapsed times quite similar. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

> and the sending time is about 4-5 ms (it depends, but this value is comparable to the ideal one, 3ms)

30Mb/s (where the b means **bits**) is approximately (give or take to account for headers etc) 3 MB/s (where the B means **bytes**). It should take roughly 30 milliseconds to transmit 100kBytes.

The `sendto` is returning as soon as it has written all the data to the local buffer of the network stack of the sending machine.  The `recv` obviously has to wait for the data to be transmitted, including latency and stuff needed for all the layers of protocols.

Comment: Sorry for the bad sending time estimation. So, if the elapsed time of 4-5 ms is actually the time of writing the data to the local buffer, sendto returns even if all the data are not actually sent?